How to render VueJs component inside loaded partial
I am using a dialog vue component to load a partial (blade view) to show as the content of the dialog. This works fine except when I start adding a vue component inside that partial view.
In Dialog.vue I use theses methods for loading a partial:
 loadPartial() {
        axios.get('/dialogs/' + this.partial).then(response => {
            this.html = response.data;

        }).catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
    }

computed: {
    htmlText() {
        return `${this.html}`;
    }
}

Inside <template> there is this to catch the partial's content:
 <div v-html="htmlText" class="l-dialog__content">
 </div>

The partial is called from a blade view with for example:
<hh-dialog placeholder="{{ __('Loading...') }}" partial="close-advertisement">
    <template v-slot:activator="{ onClick }">
        <a @click="onClick" class="m-button" href="javascript:">
             <i class="m-button__icon fa fa-trash"></i>
         </a>
    </template>
</hh-dialog>

The problem is that when the partial (in this case close-advertisement.blade.php) has a Vue component inside of it. It won't render.
So inside my partial this bit won't render:
<div class="mb-2">
   <hh-reason-picker action="advertisement.close"></hh-reason-picker>
 </div>

So. How do I render a Vue component that is inside a dialog's partial, loaded with a get request?

What do you do to render the component? The question needs https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

For the initial dialog component I use createApp() with all the components inside.

Please, provide relevant code, there should be enough of it to reproduce the problem. It's unclear how the thing looks in whole. Does "htmlText" contain the string you called a partial, "<hh-dialog ..."? It can't work this way, this is a template and not just "html". "inside my partial this bit won't render" - how is this bit related to a partial?

Not having found a real answer, I ended up loading the blade view into a Vue slot instead of doing a get request.
The dialog component is called this way now:
                  <hh-dialog placeholder="{{ __('Loading...') }}">
                        <template v-slot:partial>
                            @include('dialogs/close-advertisement')
                        </template>
                        <template v-slot:activator="{ onClick }">
                            <a title="{{ __('Close') }}" @click="onClick" class="m-button" href="javascript:">
                                <i class="m-button__icon fa fa-exclamation"></i>
                            </a>
                        </template>
                    </hh-dialog>

Inside Dialog.vue:
<template>
     <div class="l-dialog" :class="{'active':active}">
      <!-- Get request partial -->
      <div v-if="htmlText" class="l-dialog__content" v-html="htmlText"></div>

      <!-- Slot partial -->
      <slot name="partial"/>
    </div>
</template>

It work's fine. But without the get request the pages does load it multiple times without realy needing the partials to be there.
